# Integrating sonarqube with Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube

I am trying to run sonar `sonar:sonar` by integrating sonarqube and jenkins. While doing, am getting the below error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project iwm_common: Can not execute SonarQube analysis: org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext -> [Help 1]
```

Jenkins version - 1.612

Sonarqube version - 3.6

JDK-1.7.0_76

Maven - 3.1.1

Jenkins WAR is deployed in server A and sonarqube is deployed in server B. I have not installed `sonar-jenkins` plugin in Jenkins.

Can anyone let me know whether `sonar-jenkins` plugin is mandatory to be installed in jenkins to integrate jenkins with any sonar server (eg:sonarqube).

If the answer is `YES`, then after installation of the required plugin, will adding the sonar server (eg:sonarqube) information under `Manage Jenkins -> Configure system -> sonar` resolve the above error ?

The error is related to `sonar-maven-plugin` and this plugin is not used in any of the project's pom.xml. Can anyone please explain whether this plugin gets referred as a part of `sonar:sonar` goal. Thanks.

Comment: Starting by sharing the full Maven error stack trace would be a good beginning. Moreover the 3.6 version is very old and not supported anymore. The current LTS version is 4.5.4.

Comment: any updates in this? coz am facing the same challenge?

Comment: Using latest version of sonarqube resolved the issue mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The versions you specified are not compatible for running sonar analysis.

Please upgrade SonarQube version (current is 5.1.1) which requires

Java 1.7-1.8
SonarQube 5.0 or 5.1.1
Sonar-runner 2.4

Answer (score 0):

Using latest version of sonarqube resolved the issue mentioned.